# Negative points when Flaging

Tags: discussion, flagging, voting

Does one gets Negative points for Flagging something to Moderator?

Comment: Link to the post? Why did you flag your own post?

Comment: did I do that :(, that sucks !

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood - I guess you were asking if flagging post A would deduct rep on post B if you posted B on the same question as A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, see [Help Center > Privileges > Flag Posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for details.

Comment: Got it, so just some passing by jerk, felt to downvote with no reason. Why is it then allowed to answer almost copy exact the answer already given without Moderator intervention?

Comment: Moderators don't read all the questions and answers on the site (at least I don't and I would be surprised if my fellow mods do). If something requires moderator invention, please flag the post.

Comment: That's the reason I am asking, I did flag it (and got negative vote) so was just wondering if the 2 are related.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Characterizing a down vote as "some passing jerk" seems a bit thin skinned by you as well as aggressive to feedback. If you happen to be referring to your flag on [dwightk](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124535/5472)'s post - we rarely step in and delete a duplicate answer until a week has passed. I meant to decline the flag, but marked it helpful accidentally. What if your down voter accidentally did so? It is after all, one person on the internet at this point.

Comment: I can not stand people giving they opinion specialty the negative one (thus jerk) without explaining them self, since that will certainly not help me improving my answers.

Comment: @Buscar웃 neither up- nor downvotes need to be explained. We get flags on comments asking for explanation of downvotes (and tend to delete such comments).

Comment: Thanks,its a beer time, I am clearly taking all this to personally.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Beer time indeed. I hope it's tasty and refreshing. Thanks for being light hearted.

Comment: Since i created confusion, and I am sorry, this is what I am talking about     http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124535/46541

and this users answer user:70930 which is exactly same as mine ? I flagged that, but don't worry, just point stuff out.

Comment: If it helps, I posted that answer and noticed that your answer was already up after I posted it. It was not when I began writing the answer. I noticed that your original answer did not describe how to do what your picture showed, so I left my answer.

Comment: Here is a gem of a summary post on why down voting can be fraught with pitfalls for the person receiving the vote and the person casting the vote and for someone who comments but didn't even vote (or voted in a direction opposite what someone suspected). [How to Guarantee Getting Downvotes Without an Explanation](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/how-to-guarantee-getting-downvotes-without-explanation)